# Get Windows Task Managers Application Tab

Tags: powerbuilder

How can I scan through the "Windows Task Manager" Applications tab using Powerbuilder?  I want to be able to read through all the programs currently running under the Applications tab and get the name of each program and it's process ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes little sense: "Applications" tab of the Windows Task Manager does not list a process ID (which is because not every entry in that list must be a unique process). I'm assuming you rather meant the "Processes" tab.

I don't know about Powerbuilder's capabilities, but if you want to get a list of "all running processes", you don't want to bother reading another applications "output", but rather query it directly from the system (either using the Windows Api, WMI, etc.):

- [Get full running process list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477097/21567)

Note that "all running processes" is rather vague also. All running processes of all logged on users? Or just those of the current user. Mind you, that you might not have sufficient permissions to see (all details) of processes that don't belong to your user.

Consider posting another question, telling us what you are actually trying to achieve (what you want to use the information for).

Comment: i know "Applications" tab doesn't show process id.but i want "Applications" tab task name and status using process id.i have process id.Using that process id how i get task name and status?

Comment: The Applications tab is basically filled by enumerating all top-level windows (in reality it is a bit more complicated). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3382513/21567) is an example doing it in Delphi.